# Bind Scope in ReactStore method to use setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm trying to update the StoreState via the setState(); method,
I'm getting back a 'this.setState() is undefined' which seems to me 
like a scoping issue.

I'm trying to bind the scope to the function to set Store state from this method
(see in constructor or in AppDispatcher) but it didn't work out.
So i guess i have to bind the scope in a different way/somewhere else?

Can anybody help out?

```
import AppDispatcher from '../appDispatcher.jsx';
import Events from 'events';
import axios from 'axios';

class FavoritesStore extends EventEmitter {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //doesn't do the trick
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        importError: 'foo'
    };

}


updateState() {
    console.log('update state called');
    // this line prints this.setState is undefined
    this.setState('importError', 'is-active');
}

}

var favObj = new FavoritesStore();

AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
  var action = payload.action;
  switch (action.actionType) {
    case 'UPDATE_ID':
        favObj.updateState(action.data);
        // this does not help it
        // favObj.updateState(action.data).bind(this);

        break;
}

return true;
});

export default favObj;
```

Comment: did you try `this.setState( {importError: 'is-active'} )`?

Comment: yep, did not help.

Answer (score 2):

The bind is okay, but `EventEmitter` is a node class and not a react component, so it doesn't maintain a state or have a `setState` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But this this.state in constructor is working.. and i can access the state property in other components. Is there a way to update the "state" in an eventemitter?

Comment: The `state` property that you've declared here can simply be updated with `this.state.importError = 'is-active'`. Since it's not a react state, you don't have the accompanying restrictions (but you also don't have any of the functionality.) It's just a property. I wouldn't call it `state` though, as that can get confusing in a react environment. [reposted this comment to fix mistake in markup]